# Does OpenCL guarantee buffer memory integrity with multiple command queues?

Tags: gpu, opencl

**Simplified problem**
I have two host threads, each with its own command queue to the same GPU device. Both queues are out-of-order with the execution order explicitly managed using wait events (simplified example doesn't need this, but actual application does).

`ThreadA` is a lightweight processing pipeline that runs in real-time as new data is acquired. `ThreadB` is a heavyweight slower processing pipeline that uses the same input data but processes it asynchronously at a slower rate. I'm using a double buffer to keep the pipelines separate but allow `ThreadB` to work on the same input data written to device by `ThreadA`.

`ThreadA`'s loop:

1. Pulling image from network as data is available
2. Write image to device `cl_mem BufferA` using `clEnqueueWriteBuffer(CommandQueueA)`
3. Invoke image processing `KernelA` using `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(CommandQueueA)` once write is complete (kernel outputs results to `cl_mem OutputA`)
4. Read processed result from `OutputA` using `clEnqueueReadBuffer(CommandQueueA)`

`ThreadB`'s loop

1. Wait until enough time has elapsed (does work at slower rate)
2. Copy `BufferA` to `BufferB` using `clEnqueueCopyBuffer(CommandQueueB)` (double buffer swap)
3. Invoke slower image processing `KernelB` using `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(CommandQueueB)` once copy is complete (kernel outputs results to `cl_mem OutputB`)
4. Read processed result from `OutputB` using `clEnqueueReadBuffer(CommandQueueB)`

**My Questions**

There's a potential race condition between `ThreadA`'s step 2 and `ThreadB`'s step 2. I don't care which is executed first, I just want to make sure I don't copy `BufferA` to `BufferB` while `BufferA` is being written to.

1. Does OpenCL provide any implicit guarantees that this won't happen?
2. If not, if I instead on `ThreadB` step 2 use `clEnqueueCopyBuffer(CommandQueueA)` so that both the write and copy operations are in the same command queue, does that guarantee that they can't run simultaneously even though the queue allows out-of-order execution?
3. If not, is there a better solution than adding the WriteBuffer's event in `ThreadA` to the waitlist of the CopyBuffer command in `ThreadB`?

It seems like any of these should work, but I can't find where in the OpenCL spec it says this is fine. Please cite the OpenCL spec in your answers if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does OpenCL provide any implicit guarantees that this won't happen?

No, there is no implicit synchronization unless you use a single in-order command queue.

> If not, if I instead on ThreadB step 2 use
>   clEnqueueCopyBuffer(CommandQueueA) so that both the write and
>   copy operations are in the same command queue, does that
>   guarantee that they can't run simultaneously even though the
>   queue allows out-of-order execution?

No, regardless of a queue's type (in-order vs out-of-order),
OpenCL runtime does not track memory dependencies of
commands. User is responsible to specify events in a wait list,
if any dependency between commands exists.

The following quote could serve as a proof of that:

> s3.2.1 Execution Model: Context and Command Queues
>
> Out-of-order Execution: Commands are issued in order, but do
>   not wait to complete before following commands execute.  Any
>   order constraints are enforced by the programmer through
>   explicit synchronization commands.

It is not a direct answer to your question, but I assume that if
any guarantees were provided, they should be mentioned in this
section.

> If not, is there a better solution than adding the
>   WriteBuffer's event in ThreadA to the waitlist of the
>   CopyBuffer command in ThreadB?

If you can use a single in-order queue, that would probably be
more efficient than a cross-queue event, at least for some
implementations.